# Server Side (Code Behind) Yes No Confirmation Message Box in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side, messagebox

i am developing asp.net web application, in that i need to use server side yes/no message box, i searched all the places but i have not found a good solution,

**i found only client side javascript yes/no message box only, like below code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" OnClick = "OnConfirm" Text = "Raise Confirm" OnClientClick = "Confirm()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
if (confirmValue == "Yes")
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
}
else
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
}
}
```

but this solution not helped me, i need fully server side yes/no message box in asp.net c#.. i search & tried the below code, but its executed partially.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
                    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
                    sb.Append("confirm('");
                    sb.Append("Hi");
                    sb.Append("')};");
                    sb.Append("</script>");
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "confirm", sb.ToString());


                    string msg = "Do you want to save data?";                        
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "confirm('" + msg + "')", true);
}
```

in the above code, i need when we click **yes** option need to go 
Yes block / when we click No Option it need to move no block.

i don't know how to do this..
i tried below code

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
                    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
                    sb.Append("confirm('");
                    sb.Append("Hi");
                    sb.Append("')};");
                    sb.Append("</script>");
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "confirm", sb.ToString());


                    string msg = "Do you want to save data?";                        
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "confirm('" + msg + "')", true);

string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm"];
                    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                    {
                        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
                    }
}
```

any body help me..

Comment: Unless your users can walk into the data center, log into your server, and click the appropriate button, I'm not sure how a "server side" dialog would ever work. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: thank you for your response, sorry sir, its not help me..

Comment: "its not help me" - again, *what are you trying to achieve*? Just because you *want* to do this doesn't mean you **can**.

Comment: Server side isn't really possible on what your trying to achieve, you need either need a javascript alert or you need something like a bootstrap modal with asp.net controls \ buttons that will cause a postback event.

Answer (score 1):

Put your custom confirmation in client side code (javascript + html Modal)

Then simply call the javascript function from C# code-behind

```
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0fscmf3L/">Example</a>
```